# 2006 Ford Fiesta front left wheel clicking with each rotation

Tags: brakes, noise, wheels, clicking

my Fiesta has a clicking noise on front left that happens with each tire rotation on a specific spot. It's always a single click, not a rattle or something similar. The brake pads are gripping the brake disc a bit and it's harder to rotate the tire by hand on the spot that produces the clicking noise. This noise goes away when the brakes are applied. I dropped the tire and after rotating the wheel without the tire, I think I don't heard any clicking. Also checked the wheel bearing, that seem to be fine.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ETFTO8w9uzD0x8ufKm2VMLdj5evEEYpw/view?usp=sharing

Any idea what that might be? What should I check next?

Comment: If you turn the steering fully in both directions, does it still click?

Comment: To hopefully flesh out what Howie is saying, if you turn the steering wheel fully (one way or the other) and rotate the wheel, does it still click? Is it worse? Try this both ways, left and right.

Comment: Will check later today, thanks for the tip. What should it indicate? If it stops clicking in one way or the other, what does that mean?

Comment: It could be a worn Constant velocity joint. It does sound like it could be.  Turning the steering puts the CV joint in a different position where it may not click, or may be worse.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common symptom of a worn constant velocity joint.  The CV joint connects the driveshaft to the hub.  It allows the hub to move with the steering while still allowing the driveshaft to connect to the gearbox.

The most common reason for the CV joint to fail is that the protective rubber gaiter that covers the CV joint has split, allowing dirt inside.

Try turning the steering fully to each end then rotate the wheel again.  Does this make the clicking better or worse?

You can also look for splits in the rubber covering the CV joint.

[image]

I got this photo from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QlSHF5y8ZaI) video where someone is replacing Fiesta CV joints.